# Is it possible to use a variable in a .cs file in a .cshtml.cs file to display its value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to integrate my console application into a ASP.NET Core Web Application, in which I used the Program.cs file to put my console code (works fine from what I see). And I want to use a variable from that Program.cs file in my Index.cshtml.cs file so that it will display the value generated on the Index.cshtml page. I hope this explained it simply, if not please let me know.

In the end of it, I want to get the variable adultScore set in the Program Main and access it on the Index.cshtml.cs.

I have tried referencing the namespace of a different project in the same solution, to get some form of connection with the Program class in that project, in which seemed like I was going in the wrong direction.

So I instead tried referencing whatever I could such as the objects, classes, namespace, just to see if I could get some form of reference to what I wanted. There has to be a correct and logical method to doing this.

```cs
Program p = new Program();
Double score;
score = p.adultScore;
Message = score;
```

I expect adultScore to set a value it retains in Program.cs and put it against Message

> 'Program' does not contain a definition for 'adultScore' and no accessible extension method 'adultScore' accepting a first argument type 'Program' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: `I have been trying to integrate my console application into a ASP.NET Core Web Application` Just because you can, that doesn't mean you should. Refactoring your code into a set of common library/libraries that both applications use would be a much cleaner and more maintainable approach.

Comment: Ok @KennethK. I will definitely give that approach a try! Cheers.

Comment: By the way, the error message is pretty clear.  If you look at your Program class, my guess is that you will not find a public field, property (or any other kind of public member) named `adultScore`.